# LDAP schema editing on the fly

Tags: ldap, schema, openldap

Is it possible in any of the existing LDAP servers to edit a schema in one of the editors available? Like JXplorer, Apache Directory Studio, LDAP Admin?

I tried with OpenLDAP and all of the above tools (I run the server with -F option) but it looks like it's not possible to modify schema - add new attributes, add descriptions etc.

I would be grateful if any of you have some experience with this.

Cheers

Comment: Apache Studio will edit the schema of Apache Directory.

Most can be done with importing an LDIF file.

As changes to the schema is a rare event the current restrictions do not seem like a burden.

Perhaps you should explain the current problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I just want to allow more people to edit schema (grafically and easily). Imagine I want to allow them to add description to attributes - that would make schema changes quite often

Comment: Whatever schema changes you make online won't take effect until you restart the server. You really *don't* want multiple people to be able to edit your schema. Only the LDAP adminstrator should do that, if ever. I've never done it in 9 years of using LDAP.

Answer (score 2):

Some LDAP servers allow (authorized users) to change the schema by sending LDAP modify operation affecting the so-called [subschema subentry](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#section-4.2) directly, but not OpenLDAP.

In OpenLDAP you have two possible configuration methods:

- Static file configuration usually with schema files being simply included (aka *slapd.conf*) which requires slapd to be restarted to make configuration changes effective
- Dynamic configuration backend [back-config](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd-config) (aka *cn=config*) for which you can also define ACLs restricting access to your LDAP admins

The dynamic configuration method allows to tweak the schema via LDAP making it effective without server-restart. But you have to modify the multiple LDAP entries in sub-tree [cn=schema,cn=config](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html#cn=schema) which you can do with any generic LDAP client.

Since schema descriptions usually reference other schema descriptions the order is important. Standard LDAP does not know about order of entries beneath an entry or order of attribute values. Therefore OpenLDAP implements an extension specified in [draft-chu-ldap-xordered](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-chu-ldap-xordered).